# Python: Df takes Data from Df before

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

´´´
import ssl
import smtplib
import pandas as pd
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
googlenews = GoogleNews()
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As `get_news()` doesn't accept a list, a straight forward approach would be to iterate over all your locations using a `for`loop. Then, save all the separate DFs in a list and finally concat them.

Make sure to use `clear()` to clear your previous search.

```
import ssl
import pandas as pd
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews
ssl._create_default_https_context = ssl._create_unverified_context
googlenews = GoogleNews()
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8')
googlenews.set_lang('en')
googlenews.set_period('7h')

cities = ['New York', 'Los Angeles', 'London', 'Munich', 'Amsterdam', 'Madrid']
messages = []

for city in cities:
    googlenews.clear()
    googlenews.get_news(city)
    new_table = []
    for row in googlenews.results():
        new_table.append({
            'City': city,
            'Title': row['title'],
            'Date': row['date'],
            'Link': row['link'],
            'Source': row['site'],
        })
    df = pd.DataFrame(tabelle_neu)

    if not df.empty:
      df['Link'] = df.apply(lambda row: \
                            "<a href='{}' target='_blank'>{}</a>".format(row.Link,
                            row.Link.split('/')[2]), axis=1)
      messages.append(df)

df_total = pd.concat(messages, axis='index')

# drop duplicates with same title
df_total.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True)

pd.DataFrame.to_csv(df_total)
```

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply. The reason why I used three tables was that I wanted to see for each message to which keyword it belongs. Thus, there was always a column indicating to which keyword the message belongs. Is there a way to keep this column?

Comment: Unfortunately, this code also repeats the messages over and over again.

Comment: @David_Python I updated my answer. Also added th `clear()` statement to get rid of duplicates.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when I run the code, unfortunately I do not get the same output ... At the end I send the composite dataframes as mail

Comment: @David_Python How is it different? Do you get different news? Or do you still have duplicates?

Comment: For example, if I type 6 cities in the list, I get the news for one city displayed 3 times....

Comment: @David_Python I changed the indentation in the code above. I get `dfgesamt['Title'].value_counts().max()` is 1. Please be aware some articles can also be assigned to multiple locations. You could delete duplicates with `dfgesamt.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True)`.

Comment: Thanks, but now I get a huge error: Wrong number of items passed 0, placement implies 1

Comment: @David_Python This happens if you concat empty DataFrames if there are no news. Could you share your list of locations please?

Comment: But without the line: dfgesamt.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True) I don't get the error.... Only there I have the error on the 3rd element of my list (place 2) that all corresponding messages are listed three times.

Comment: @David_Python I updated the solution to include a check for empty DFs. Not sure, if it has to do with filtering. In my tests it appeared, if no news were found.

Comment: When I run your updated code from above, I get the KeyError: Index(['Title'], dtype='object')

Comment: I have updated the code above: This code gives me the messages for the 3rd keyword a total of 3 times in a row.

Comment: @David_Python look into it, once the edit is accepted by the mods. However, I can not observe it for the given sample. You can checkt that in this [Jupyter Notebook](https://colab.research.google.com/drive/1rsSKxMorULL3fukUdqLhQlA5MUbHZ9dQ?usp=sharing)

Comment: Can you show your results here?

Comment: @David_Python With your edit in, I do get duplicates e. g. `'Champions League: Bayern-Star Robert Lewandowski jagt Ronaldo-Rekord'`, as the article is tagged with multiple locations e. g. 'Amsterdam' and 'Madrid'. This is not due to the Scraping but due to Google News. It's your decision, whether you want to add the filtering for duplicates back in.

Comment: Mate my problem is the following: I get for example three News for the third keyword in the list. These three messages are displayed to me a total of nine times. The problem occurs only for the third keyword in the list. And when I add this: dfgesamt.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True) to my code then I get the following Keyerror: Inden(['Title'], dtype='object')  although without this line I get the messages for all keywords.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the duplicates from messages.append(df) based on the titles?

Comment: You could try `df.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True)`.

Comment: Unfortunately, this does not work ...

Comment: Could check this question? Probably you can edit it there https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71757193/python-dataframe-loop-repeats-by-only-one-element

Comment: @David_Python I answered your question. After your edit it wasn't runnable... Please run my code without further edits in a fairly recent python installation.