# Python: Dataframe loop repeats by only one element

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, google-news

When I run the code and output it, I notice that the messages for the third item in the list are output three times in a row. With the previous and subsequent elements from the list it works problem los. Can anyone help me with this, or does anyone know how to at least remove such duplicates?

```
Nachrichten = []
    

    
    for row in googlenews.results(): 
        table_new.append({ 
            'City': ort, 
            'Title': row['title'],  
            'URL':row['link'], 
            'Source': row['site'], }) 
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_new) 

dfges = pd.concat(nachrichten, axis='index')
´´´
```

Comment: Your indentation is off. And you're missing a newline. Could you edit your code so that we know which statements are *inside* the inner for loop, and which are outside of it?

Comment: Your format method contains two arguments, yet there is only one formatting indicator `{}` inside the string. That doesn't seem to be intended.

Comment: Unless I'm not reading correctly, you can just run apply directly on `df['URL']`. That's probably more readable than having to use `row.URL` (you can now use `row`, or rather, `link` or `url`, since it's one element, directly), and you can get rid of the axis argument: `df['URL'] = df['URL'].apply(lambda string: "{}".format(string.split('/')[2]))` or something like that.

Comment: Assuming you just want the third section of the URL when splitting by a slash, just do `df['URL'] = df['URL'].str.split('/').str[2]`.

Comment: Thank you very much, I have fixed the code now. My problem is that when I run the code, I get the results for "Madrid" three times in a row. This happens only with this one keyword, with the rest of the keywords, I get the results only once. The Lambda function is only there to make the link clickable.

Comment: You are still missing a new line near the end somewhere. Also, I'm missing the logic where, inside the inner loop, you're appending to `new_table`, but also at every iteration of the loop, you create a new dataframe from that growing `new_table`. Since you're not re-using that dataframe, nor printing or saving it, that doesn't make sense, and can be outside of the loop.

Comment: If it happens only for Madrid, you should debug your code, by printing intermediate results at various points in the code you've just shown. So that you can actually see what results you're getting back from GoogleNews before you modify them.

Comment: Is there any way to remove the duplicates from messages.append(df) based on the titles?

Comment: You was a right, now I added the last line. Could please check it up?

Comment: Have you tried debugging, as I suggested before?

Comment: There was another problem, do you probably know how to make the links clickable in the whole column?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code included some issues regarding lower and upper case e. g. `nachrichten` vs. `Nachrichten`. Python is case-sensitive though.

To answer your question, you could use `drop_duplicates()` to eliminate duplicates based on `'Title'`.

This yields:

```
dfges['Title'].value_counts().max()
>>> 1
```

**Extended code:**

```
import pandas as pd 
from GoogleNews import GoogleNews 
    
googlenews = GoogleNews() 
googlenews.set_encode('utf_8') 
googlenews.set_lang('en') 
googlenews.set_period('7d')
    
orte = ["Munich", "New York", "Madrid", "London", "Los Angeles", "Frankfurt", "Rom"] 
nachrichten = []
    
for ort in orte: 
    googlenews.clear() 
    googlenews.get_news(ort) 
    table_new = [] 
    
    for row in googlenews.results(): 
        table_new.append({ 
            'City': ort, 
            'Title': row['title'], 
            'Date': row['date'], 
            'URL':row['link'], 
            'Source': row['site'], }) 
    
        df = pd.DataFrame(table_new) 
        
    nachrichten.append(df)

dfges = pd.concat(nachrichten, axis='index')
dfges.drop_duplicates(subset=['Title'], keep='last', inplace=True)
print(dfges)
```